# Using .net functions to filter Entity Framework information

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-4.1

I have different functions that has mathematical methods and some others that has string processing methods for example some I have are: IntegralUtils.RegionalArea(double x, double y)
and StringUtils.RabinKarp(string x).

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 and when I wanted to use these kind of functions in the filter part of a Linq query there was an error that there is no such a equivalent function:

```
var res = from item  in Items
          where IntegralUtils.RegionalArea(item.X, item.Y)
          select item;
```

And my fast solution was to get all items without filtering and in a foreach loop iterate items and filter with an if expression, I think that was not the best solution of course.

But my question is if I can make entity framework to accept this kind of Linq queries with custom CLR functions or how could I make something similar?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

As @Robert McKee pointed out, you can't add your own function to the query because Entity-Framework translates your C# query into SQL and then executes it on the server. Since it doesn't know how to translate your RegionalArea method, it fails.

You can do what Robert suggested - bring all the data from SQL to your process (using the `ToList()` method), then filter the .NET collection. This will work, but might be slow if you have a lot of items in the database, and the query eventually returns only a few of them.

I wouldn't transfer your RegionalArea method to the database, that can get very messy very quickly. Instead, if performance is an issue, I would precalculate the RegionalArea for each item when adding them to the database - just add an `Item.RegionalArea` property and fill it with the proper value when constructing an item. The query then becomes trivial.

Note: Yes, I know I'm choosing a bit of denormalization over the previous solution. I think this denormalization is worth it - splitting your logic between your code and the database will cost you more.

Answer (score 1):

This will be very slow, as it has to retrieve the entire table from the database and then it will filter, but this is what you want:

```
var res=Items.ToList().Where(i=>IntegralUtils.RegionalArea(i.X,i.Y));
```

If you prefer the query syntax, I believe this will work as well:

```
var res=from item  in Items.ToList()
          where IntegralUtils.RegionalArea(item.X, item.Y)
          select item;
```

Comment: Thank you Robert, I was thinking about that and that could be the option but I was reading about predicate builer I don't know if that can help to make it faster, or the best approach is the one you mentioned?

Comment: A predicate builder won't help your performance unless your have your IntegralUtils library on the SQL Server.

Comment: This might help you after you have your function on the SQL Server http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456847%28VS.100%29.aspx